# sudo and su commands do not work, after executing sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh

Tags: osx, sudo, login

So, I've been trying to install `zsh`. It didn't work properly, after terminal restart, so I decided to change the shell again by typing `chsh -s /bin/zsh`, once again, but accidentally preceded that with `sudo`. Now if I type `sudo 'anything'` or `su -`, there appears an empty new line, with nothing I can do (nor the Ctrl+C nor the Ctrl+D do not help). What can I do to restore everything back to default? This is MacOS X 10.13

Comment: Could you post, please, output of the command: `echo $SHELL`

Comment: @Bob it’s /bin/bash

Comment: @Bob the user’s shell is okay. it’s the sudo that does not work, after trying all commands from the answer. I’ll try to post the picture

Comment: @Bob sorry, the computer is not mine, so no proper screenshots. http://imgur.com/vjiMl5J

Comment: OK, I see. My answer below is useless, I'm hiding it temporarily. Please, execute `sudo date`, press Enter key and wait up to 10-15 minutes. Has the password prompt appeared with some delay?

Comment: @Bob no.. it has not

Comment: What about `SHELL=/bin/bash sudo -s`? This should sidestep root's broken `zsh`. If that works you should have a root shell from where you can `chsh -s /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Adding sudo to your command should cause no problems unless the command was initially forbidden. The chsh command wants a password anyway. Using sudo may change the root shell but sudo should still work as before. If you are having problems I'd close the terminal and open a new one.

Comment: `chsh` won't ask for a password if you're running as root.

Comment: yea sorry..  i should have included that.